# Need to REMOVE hyphen when only on SINGLE line between time codes with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Need to REMOVE hyphen when only on SINGLE line between time codes. So in the case below only want to remove the hyphen on #24. FYI: The line could end many different chars.

```
19
00:07:03,089 --> 00:07:04,007
- Really?
- Mm-hmm.

24
00:03:01,848 --> 00:03:04,893
- How adorable.

48
00:02:53,798 --> 00:02:54,758
[clears throat]

49
00:02:57,552 --> 00:02:59,971
- [clears throat] Phil.
- What can I get you?
```

Here's what I thought might work [no cigar]:

```
Find:       ^(- )(?=.*\r?\n([A-Za-z\[]))
Replace:    - $1
```

The CORRECT end results would be as follows with hyphen removed on #24

```
19
00:07:03,089 --> 00:07:04,007
- Really?
- Mm-hmm.

24
00:03:01,848 --> 00:03:04,893
How adorable.           <<<<<---- hyphen removed

48
00:02:53,798 --> 00:02:54,758
[clears throat]

49
00:02:57,552 --> 00:02:59,971
- [clears throat] Phil.
- What can I get you?
```

Thanks in Advance, Hank

Comment: What is your programming language or regex tool?

Comment: Notepad++ .... which it did NOT work in .... another try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern to match the line before a line that starts with a hyphen and is not followed by another line that starts with a hyphen, capture the line and include the hyphen in the match, and substitute the match with what's captured but without the hyphen:

Substitute:

```
^((?!- )[^\n]*\n)- (?![^\n]*\n- )
```

with:

```
$1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xh8IsE/3